# Bring a range of holiday dates into workday arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using `WORKDAY` in my sheet to find the next working day for an array of dates. Each date has a country variable which determines the list of holidays (stored elsewhere) passed to `WORKDAY`.

I have been able to use `FILTER` to achieve this, but only when I pass a single country name to it as a condition. Ideally, I want pass the whole range of country names to it so that I can use an `ARRAYFORMULA`. After I try that, I hit the mismatched range sizes error.

Here's a link to a sample workbook: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zQiOmPxOjpkV5g05vm-1ReI-9m_AltabQamXw2iUKrI/edit?usp=sharing

[image: country variable to be used in workday arrayformula]

[image: holidays data stored here]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes its mismatched range sizes

On D2 Use This `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C2:C="",,WORKDAY(A2:A,1,FILTER(K2:K,J2:J=A2:A)) ))`

And on C2 Use this formula `=IF(A2="",,WORKDAY(A2,1,FILTER($K$2:$K$8,$J$2:$J$8=B2)))` and drag down to the bottom of the sheet.

And you will have [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDlHt.png)